# How to use selected in option attribute in name attribute using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use “selected” in option attribute in name attribute using Javascript or jQuery. It means I want to use `name="1"` option as `selected` one when the page is loaded. I tried with the below code. But it not workes.

Code:

```
<select id="countryselect" name="country">
  <option value="1" name="0">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="2" name="0">Albania</option>
  <option value="3" name="0">Algeria</option>
  <option value="4" name="1">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="5" name="0">Maldives</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#countryselect").$('option[name="1"]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/zYRkC/

Thank you.

Comment: you need to add selected attribute to the element, please check the answer below, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a second parameter to the selector to define the scope

```js
$('#countryselect').val($('option[name="1"]', "#countryselect").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countryselect" name="country">
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2" name="1">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">Malaysia</option>
<option value="5">Maldives</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put this line of code in your script-tag and it will work like you want.

```
$('#countryselect option[name="1"]').attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with dynamic assignment, you can go with

```
$("#countryselect").val(1) .
```

If selection of option is static and only want for initial load, then selected can be used for this like

```
<option value="4" selected>Malaysia</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out here 
Please click on the link to see the code [code pen link here](https://codepen.io/shankar1011/pen/abdBPBg)

```
<select id="countryselect" name="country">
    <option value="1" name="0">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2" name="0">Albania</option>
    <option value="3" name="0">Algeria</option>
    <option value="4" name="1">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="5" name="0">Maldives</option>
</select>
```

you ca use the selector to set the "**selected**" attribute like this:-

```
$("#countryselect option[name='1']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nameVal = $('[name=1]').attr('value');
$("#countryselect").val(nameVal)
```

[Codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/digitaloutback/b59srcaf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

`$("#countryselect option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");`

and if you want to select by `name` value then use

`$("#countryselect option[name='0']").attr("selected","selected");`

It will set the `selected` attribute on that option.